# Need guidance to Push Notification for iOS using Native APNs/GCM in Cordova Application

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I am using a push notification [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) in my cordova application. I was able to get the notification for Android using GCM and it was pretty easy. Now iOS which is a big pain for me since Sunday, almost 4 days now. I will share the things that i have done so far. Please help me to get the notification working on iOS devices too.

According to the plugin, on the application side my **java script** looks like this

```
myApp.controller('Register', function ($scope) {
    $scope.regGCM = function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "senderID": "41502493944",
                "sound": "true",
                "vibrate": "true",
            },
            "ios": {
                "alert": "true",
                "badge": "true",
                "sound": "true",
            },
            "windows": {}
        });
        push.on('registration', function (data) {
            var deviceid = data.registrationId;
            alert(deviceid);
        });
        push.on('notification', function (data) {
        console.log("notification");
        });
        push.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log("push error");
        });
    }
});
```

When `regGCM()` triggers iOS device asking for permission to allow the push notification for my application and it `returns a token`.

Then to test the push notification online i used this [site](http://www.pushwatch.com/apns/) which requires our `token` and `.pem` file.

To create a `.pem` file i did the following things.

1) Created a p.notification certificate from [here](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/create).
2) Installed that in mac keychain.
3) Exported installed certificate as `pushcert.p12` file.
4) Executing this command (`openssl pkcs12 -in pushcert.p12 -out pushcert.pem -nodes -clcerts`)  in terminal i got the `pushcert.pem` file.

That online testing [site](http://www.pushwatch.com/apns/) says message has sent but i never got the notification to my iOS device. I am new to push notification and don't know the correct steps, may be missing something. Is there anyone how figured iOS p.notification in cordova. I don't mind the way of doing it whether it is using GCM or native APNs. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I checked with mentioned website : http://www.pushwatch.com/apns/. It's working proper.

You are not getting push notification due to improper push certificate.

If you are not getting device token,then you can assume that certificate is not created properly.

Regards...

-Harsh Shah

Comment: Thanks for the respond =) i am new to iOS and not sure whether i followed the correct steps. I got the device token. What do you think ? May be my certificate issue ?